# XSLT: transform attribute to child element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and while transforming XML to HTML is fairly doable, I'm struggling with transforming XML to XML. What I want to do should be fairly straightforward, but I'm hopelessly stuck. Consider this XML file:

```
<cookbook xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://jg.dhlab.de/Teaching/recipe.xsd"> 
      
    <recipe name="Apple pie">
        <ingredients name='Apples'/>
        <ingredients name='Butter'/>
        <ingredients name="Flour"/>
        <ingredients name="Cinnamon"/>
        <ingredients name="Sugar"/>
        <ingredients name="Eggs"/>
        <instructions>In a small bowl, combine the sugars, flour and spices; set aside. In a large bowl, toss apples with lemon juice. Add sugar mixture; toss to coat. Line a 9-in. pie plate with bottom crust; trim even with edge. Fill with apple mixture; dot with butter. Roll remaining crust to fit top of pie; place over filling. Trim, seal and flute edges. Cut slits in crust.
            Beat egg white until foamy; brush over crust. Sprinkle with sugar. Cover edges loosely with foil. Bake at 375° for 25 minutes. Remove foil and bake until crust is golden brown and filling is bubbly, 20-25 minutes longer. Cool on a wire rack.</instructions>
    </recipe>
</cookbook>
```

I want to convert the name attribute of the ingredients element to a child element (i.e. while retaining the ingredients element. The XSL I use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ingredients">
        <xsl:element name="{name(@name)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this XSL converts the name attribute to an element but overrides the ingredients element. What I would like is the following output:

```
<recipe name="Apple pie">
    <ingredients>
        <name>Apples</name>
        <name>Butter</name>
        <name>Flour</name>
        <name>Cinnamon</name>
        <name>Sugar</name>
        <name>Eggs</name>
    </ingredients>
        <instructions>In a small bowl, combine the sugars, flour and spices; set aside. In a large bowl, toss apples with lemon juice. Add sugar mixture; toss to coat. Line a 9-in. pie plate with bottom crust; trim even with edge. Fill with apple mixture; dot with butter. Roll remaining crust to fit top of pie; place over filling. Trim, seal and flute edges. Cut slits in crust.
            Beat egg white until foamy; brush over crust. Sprinkle with sugar. Cover edges loosely with foil. Bake at 375° for 25 minutes. Remove foil and bake until crust is golden brown and filling is bubbly, 20-25 minutes longer. Cool on a wire rack.</instructions>
    </recipe>
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you want to create `name` elements then use `<name><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></name>` in the template with `match="ingredients"`.

to create the wrapper element use e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="recipe">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:where-populated>
              <ingredients>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="ingredients"/>
              </ingredients>
          </xsl:where-populated>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="* except ingredients"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ingredients">
      <name>
          <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </name>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but for whatever reason I get this result:                                  
      ```<recipe name="Apple pie">
        <name>Apples</name>
        <name>Butter</name>
        <name>Flour</name>
        <name>Cinnamon</name>
        <name>Sugar</name>
        <name>Eggs</name>
        <instructions>In a small bowl, combine the sugars....</instructions>```
    </recipe>

Comment: @Jaap, see the edit, if the transformation to `name` elements is as needed and the only missing issue is an `ingredients` parent wrapper then the edit should fix it.